# TFS, Could not find a file on the SonarQube server SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implementation.zip

Tags: tfs, sonarqube

- SonarQube version 9.6 (Community Edition) Deployed on Azure
- TFS 2018 Update 16.131 TFS
- Sonarqube extension version 4.23.1.266 (Had to use an older version
  because TFS only allowed <25mb extensions)
- Code .NET Framework 4.7.2

I deployed sonarqube using this github repo. https://github.com/vanderby/SonarQube-AzureAppService. When executing the build in TFS, I get the following error.

```
2022-09-08T07:02:17.1827740Z ##[section]Starting: [DEPRECATED] Fetch the Quality Profile from SonarQube
2022-09-08T07:02:17.1936543Z ==============================================================================
2022-09-08T07:02:17.1940305Z Task         : SonarQube for MSBuild - Begin Analysis
2022-09-08T07:02:17.1941880Z Description  : [DEPRECATED] Fetch the Quality Profile from SonarQube to configure the analysis
2022-09-08T07:02:17.1943771Z Version      : 1.0.50
2022-09-08T07:02:17.1945481Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2022-09-08T07:02:17.1946562Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=620063)
2022-09-08T07:02:17.1947917Z ==============================================================================
2022-09-08T07:02:17.2127920Z ##[warning]Task 'SonarQubePreBuild' (1.0.50) is using deprecated task execution handler. The task should use the supported task-lib: https://aka.ms/tasklib
2022-09-08T07:02:17.2137624Z Preparing task execution handler.
2022-09-08T07:02:18.4131002Z Executing the powershell script: D:\Agent\TFS_AGENT_06\_work\_tasks\SonarQubePreBuild_eae5b2cc-ac5e-4cba-b022-a06621f9c01f\1.0.50\SonarQubePreBuild.ps1
2022-09-08T07:02:18.9665316Z ##[warning] The ownership of the SonarQube related build tasks is being transferred to SonarSource.
2022-09-08T07:02:18.9674084Z ##[warning] Please replace this build task with the one brought by SonarSource's extension on the marketplace: https://aka.ms/sqextension
2022-09-08T07:02:18.9681553Z ##[warning] For more details go to https://aka.ms/sqtransfer
Removed blank lines
2022-09-08T07:02:19.6273139Z SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 1.1
2022-09-08T07:02:19.7283557Z Default properties file was not found at D:\Agent\TFS_AGENT_06\_work\_tasks\SonarQubePreBuild_eae5b2cc-ac5e-4cba-b022-a06621f9c01f\1.0.50\SonarQube.Bootstrapper\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
2022-09-08T07:02:19.7285250Z Pre-processing started.
2022-09-08T07:02:19.7285878Z Preparing working directories...
2022-09-08T07:02:19.7287268Z Checking for updates...
2022-09-08T07:02:20.2338425Z ##[error]Could not find a file on the SonarQube server. Url: https://myurl.azurewebsites.net/static/csharp/SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implementation.zip
2022-09-08T07:02:20.2342400Z ##[error]Failed to update the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild binaries. Check the server url, verify that the C# plugin is correctly installed on the SonarQube server and that the SonarQube server has been restarted.
2022-09-08T07:02:20.2344784Z ##[error]Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1
2022-09-08T07:02:20.2596838Z ##[error]System.Exception: Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 1
2022-09-08T07:02:20.2600986Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.InvokeBatchScriptCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
2022-09-08T07:02:20.2603205Z    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
2022-09-08T07:02:20.2918529Z ##[error]PowerShell script completed with 1 errors.
2022-09-08T07:02:20.2948851Z ##[section]Finishing: [DEPRECATED] Fetch the Quality Profile from SonarQube
```

I have seen multiple posts with the answer to install a C# plugin, but I am unable to find it in the plugin list. For example I found [this github page](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-.net-documentation/blob/master/doc/installation-and-configuration.md#setup-sonarqube-server) which contains a link to download the plugin, but the url is not valid anymore.